# Separating data components from real-time input coming to pc via spi in atmega32

Tags: python, csv, bluetooth, analysis

I have three atmega32 sending three sets of sensor values(accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer) to a bluetooth module over using SPI protocol. I've received the Bluetooth data, but its coming in like this,

0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,54.00

0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,51.00

0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,53.00

It's being received as a csv data and I am unable to separate the individual components. I want to store them in separate variables (like x1,y1,z1,...)

Here's my code:

```
# Author: P. Vinod Ranganath
# Description: Receiving data from ATmega32 via bluetooth
# Date: 27/04/2015


import bluetooth
import sys

#address of the bluetooth device
addr = "00:06:66:61:1E:76"
#port number
port = 1

#create socket and connect to it
socket = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
socket.connect((addr, port))




#if there is an incoming transmission, enter loop
while True:
    #receive transmitted data
    data = socket.recv(1024) 

    #print data
    sys.stdout.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has a `csv` module, that does all the CSV parsing you'd typically want.

In your case, it's even simpler: Strings in python have the `split(char)` method, so

```
data.split(",")
```

should give you an array of the substrings:

```
["0.0", "0.0", ....
```

Now, you want to have floating point numbers, right?

Stick to your favourite Python tutorial (really, read one!) and do

```
values = [float(substring) for substring in data.split(",")]
```

so that `values` is an array of floating point numbers.

You can then do something like

```
x1 = values[10]
```

But you typically don't want to do that --- having this kind of data as an array is usually more useful.

Comment: Bro, it's giving me an output like this,                                                                       ['', '0.00', '0.0'] ['0', '51.00\r\n0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '54.00\r\n0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '53.00\r\n0.00', '']                                                                                                                                                        and when I try to convert it into float, it's throwing me an error saying, invalid literal

Comment: I guess it throws the error when the float conversion comes across the end of each line where it has \r and \n (by default).

Comment: i'm now trying to eliminate \r and \n at the end of each line...........any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_words(data):
      l = []
      w = ''
     for c in data.lower():
          if c in '\r \n ,':
              if w != '': 
                 l.append(w)
                 w = ''
              else:
                 w = w + c
          if w != '': 
              l.append(w)
return l
```

found this on stack overflow.

It separates the different elements and float conversion proceeds without errors.But, the list isn't getting filled in order(last item to second place and so on, randomly)

Comment: X1 = 0.0  Y1 = 0.0  Z1 = 0.0  X2 = 0.0  Y2 = 0.0  Z2 = 0.0  X3 = 0.0  Y3 = 53.0  Z3 = 0.0  T = 0.0
X1 = 0.0  Y1 = 0.0  Z1 = 0.0  X2 = 0.0  Y2 = 0.0  Z2 = 0.0  X3 = 51.0  Y3 = 0.0  Z3 = 0.0  T = 0.0                                                                               Look at 53.0, its changing places, cuz the list is being filled out of order